# parsing JSON using GSON issue

Tags: android, json, gson

Problems in parsing the Nested key value pairs in JSON.

JSON  Structure.

```
 {  
   "data":{  
      "action":"item1",
      "react":"item2",
        "categories":{  
         "Price":{  
            "$0-$10":{  
               "Refine":"false",
               "bcc":"2"               
            },
            "$251-$500":{  
               "Refine":"false",
               "bcc":"2"
            }
         },
         "Gender":{  
            "Girl":{  
              "Refine":"false",
               "bcc":"2"
            },
            "Boy":{  
            "Refine":"false",
               "bcc":"2"
            }
         }
    }
}}
```

Defined the following class as POJO

```
class Product
{
public Data data;

public class Data{

   public String action;

   public String react;

   public Map<String,Map<String,request>> categories;

}}

public class request{
  public string Refine;
  public String bcc
}
```

The key value pair in JSON element 'categories'  is dynamic.

```
Product responseData = gson.fromJson(jsoninput,
                Product.class);
```

Tried to parse the above mentioned JSON using gson and pogo class Product

1. fields action, react are parsed correct.
2. field categories returned empty Map.

Comment: "the above code returned empty MyMap" , what is above code? can you rename the json MyMap and your class MyMap to avoid confusion. and can you again restate your question with good description of what you want.

Comment: thanks for your response, I have defined a POGO class to match JSON structure and class members for deserialization.

Comment: I solved your issue , want to post it or you have already solve it?

Comment: I am still working on  it. would be great if you could post the solution.. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using GSON version 2.3 download it from maven.
just create a project copy all of them in it and set json file path and press RUN:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;


public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Gson gson = new Gson();


        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader("your json file path"));

            // Deserialization
            Product obj = gson.fromJson(br, Product.class);


            // Serialization
            gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(obj);
            System.out.println(json);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

your POJO Class:

```
import java.util.Map;


class Product
{
    public Data data;

    public class Data{

        public String action;

        public String react;

        public class request{
            public String Refine;
            public String bcc;
        }

        public Map<String,Map<String,request>> categories;

    }
}
```

and finally your json string:

```
   {
       "data":{  
         "action":"item1",
         "react":"item2",
         "categories":{  
            "Price":{  
               "$0-$10":{  
                  "Refine":"false",
                  "bcc":"2"               
               },
               "$251-$500":{  
                  "Refine":"false",
                  "bcc":"2"
               }
            },
            "Gender":{  
               "Girl":{  
                 "Refine":"false",
                  "bcc":"2"
               },
               "Boy":{  
               "Refine":"false",
                  "bcc":"2"
               }
            }
        }

       }
     }
```

Comment: trying to understand your solution.. looks like exactly what I posted (tried) before.

Comment: testing the solution.